# Using only one parameter in ComponentName method in android

Tags: android

In my app I am using `ComponentName` to get the package name of launched app like this:

```
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(
                event.getPackageName().toString(),
                event.getClassName().toString()
        );
```

The above code is working perfectly.So, the problem is that I want the package name only I don't want the class name,the above code gives both package name as well as class name.I tried to remove `event.getClassName().toString()` parameter from it and I tried to replace it with null but it gives Exception and crashes.
So how to get the package name only from the above code..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the package name from the application context. Try it with this code :

```
try {
    String packageName = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I'm glad to help you :) Thanks for correct answer :P

Comment: For safety reasons,I want to add try catch block for it to handle exceptions how can i do that

Comment: I edit my answer, we use e.printStackTrace() if we have some error (exception) to show it in the Android Monitor.

Answer (score 0):

> So, the problem is that I want the package name only I don't want the class name,the above code gives both package name as well as class name.

That is not possible. A component is a class. A `ComponentName`, therefore, must point to a class. We use the combination of package name (to identify the app containing the class) and the class (to identify the specific component within the app).